# Using the series of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ for calculating $\pi$

Tags: taylor-expansion

> The power series expansion of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ is 
>   $$\tan^{-1}(x)=x-\frac 13 x^3+\frac 15 x^5-\frac 17 x^7+ \cdots .$$
>   Use the above series to determine a series for calculating $\pi$.

Comment: Your post is presently (close to) unreadable. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: just subs $x=1$ in the series you are given.

Comment: Why don't you go with [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/is-value-of-pi-4/)

Answer (score 4):

Your series is :
$$\arctan(x)=x-\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^5}5-\frac{x^7}7+\cdots$$
(this is easy to obtain from $\ \displaystyle\arctan(x)=\int \frac {dx}{1+x^2}$ using Taylor series)

A simple result is :
$$\arctan(1)=\frac{\pi}4=1-\frac 13+\frac 15-\frac 17+\cdots$$

so that multiplying by $4$ ... but the convergence is [very slow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80).

Other formulas are more useful like (John Machin 1706) and [many others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula) :
$$\frac {\pi}4= 4\,\arctan\left(\frac 15\right)-\arctan\left(\frac 1{239}\right)$$
(see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) for other methods)